# Xcode, ios, Set name of variable to value of another variable?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring

I want to set the name of a variable to the value of another variable are there any other ways to do this because I don't think this is the way.

```
NSString *myint = @"a";

NSString *([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myint]) = @"something";

NSLog(@"%@", a);
```

Comment: Can you perhaps achieve what you want using an `NSDictionary`?

Answer (score 1):

**No, you can't do that.** Once your code is compiled, your variables don't really have names -- just locations. The names you see in the debugger are provided by a symbol file which the debugger uses to map locations to names.

**Key-value coding could help**, depending on what you're really trying to accomplish. With KVC, you use key names to refer to values rather than accessing variables, much as you do with a dictionary. For example, if you have an object with properties `foo` and `bar`, you can then do something like this:

```
NSString *key = @"foo";
[myObject setValue:@(5) forKey:key];
```

You could even override `-setValue:forKey:` so that it accepts any key and remembers the value (which is exactly what a dictionary does).

**You can go in the other direction** (set a variable to the name of another variable) using the [stringification operator](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html), but it's kinda hacky and not usually all that useful. In a nutshell, macro parameters prefixed with a # are used as literal strings instead of being evaluated. So you'd create a macro like this:

```
#define string(x) #x
```

and then you'd use it somewhere in your code like this:

```
int foo = 5;
NSLog("The name of the variable is %s and its value is %d.", string(foo), foo);
```

with the following result:

```
The name of the variable is foo and its value is 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Paulw11. You could define a NSMutableDictionary to hold all your variables by key. I don't think there is any way the compiler can use a handle determined at runtime. But you can achieve the same affect.

So say, for instance, that both the variable handle and value were `NSString`, then you could do something like this.

```
NSMutableDictionary *myObjects = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] init];

NSString variableName = @"myString";

[myObjects setObject @"Variable value" forKey: variableName];

NSLog("Variable %@ has value %@.", variableName, [myObjects objectForKey: variableName]);
```

Comment: I believe if you replaced @["variable value"] with @(insert integer here) that it would all still work but with integers.